# How to command the raspberry pi to mute and unmute its microphone

Tags: audio, lxterminal, microphone

I'm using a raspberry pi for a custom voice assistant I'm building. I need to mute and unmute the microphone for certain parts of the program I'm running. Is there a simple lx terminal command to do this? I'm using a voice hat from AIY projects if that makes any difference. I'm not using a usb mic.

Comment: if I have to start a bounty for this please upvote this question so I can continue to ask questions in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`amixer`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/amixer):

```
amixer sset 'Capture' cap
amixer sset 'Capture' nocap
```

You may have to find out the control name for the microphone in your setup if you use additional hardware. `amixer scontrols` will list the controls you have.

There's also [`pactl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pactl) command which should work on PulseAudio level. Identify the mic in the output of `pactl list sources` and then mute / unmute the source by number

```
pactl set-source-mute 0 1 # mute source 0
pactl set-source-mute 0 0 # unmute source 0
```

Comment: please explain the "pactl" more, my rpi recognizes the microphone on pulseaudio. thanks for the info so far

Comment: You can also do `amixer sset Capture toggle`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building voice assistant, instead of muting microphone. I suggest to disable / enable the wake word listener. If you are using MyCroft, then MyPrecise is the work word listener which you can disable and enable when required

Comment: That is not how my recognizer works, I specifically need the mic muted

Comment: Try 

**amixer set Mic nocap** to mute &

**amixer set Mic cap** to unmute

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any [shell commands](https://wiki.debian.org/ShellCommands) that is designed for it, but if we assume your microphone is connected via USB, you can disable and enable the specific USB port.

First check the path of your device via `lsusb -t`.

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
```

To disable hub: `echo '1-1.1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`. You can again enable it via binding it. The detailed discussion is available [here.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=172313)

Comment: this is not a usb device it is built on a Aiy kit

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that